# Spinner and WheelView together

Tags: android

I`m not able to select the spinner while using with  https://github.com/LukeDeighton/WheelView

its working separately but,what i have done is just added both in xml and set adaptor for spinner still its not working please help.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv" />

    <com.lukedeighton.wheelview.WheelView
        android:id="@+id/wheelview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/refresh"
        app:emptyItemColor="@color/green_900"
        app:repeatItems="true"
        app:rotatableWheelDrawable="false"
        app:selectionAngle="90.0"
        app:selectionColor="@color/teal_900"
        app:selectionPadding="4dp"
        app:wheelColor="@color/grey_400"
        app:wheelItemCount="14"
        app:wheelItemRadius="41dp"
        app:wheelPadding="13dp"
        app:wheelPosition="bottom"
        app:wheelRadius="276dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of relative layout change as follows :

```
      <Spinner
           android:id="@+id/spinner2"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="50dp"
           android:layout_below="@+id/tv" />

      <com.lukedeighton.wheelview.WheelView
           android:id="@+id/wheelview"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_below="@+id/spinner2"
           app:emptyItemColor="@color/green_900"
           app:repeatItems="true"
           app:rotatableWheelDrawable="false"
           app:selectionAngle="90.0"
           app:selectionColor="@color/teal_900"
           app:selectionPadding="4dp"
           app:wheelColor="@color/grey_400"
           app:wheelItemCount="14"
           app:wheelItemRadius="41dp"
           app:wheelPadding="13dp"
           app:wheelPosition="bottom"
           app:wheelRadius="276dp" />
```